# Firing a bigQuery query on editing a particular column in google sheets

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-bigquery

/*    I am new to app scripting and I have a very specific question. I have a sheet with column A. Whenever this sheet is changed to add/edit the column A, i need to trigger bigQuery query and update results in another column B. I used onedit() function but it does not run the bigQuery query. I also tried using an installable trigger but still no luck. Any advice on how to handle such scenario.

```
Issue 1: Only top edited row is added to array " dat"
      2: The function runBigQuery is not triggered. */

Script:
function onMyEdit(e){
// Trying to find if the edited sheet is 'A' and column is 25. If so, I //want to get edited value(s) in the column 25 and add to an array

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var range = e.range;
  var colZ=range.getColumn()+1;
  var dat=[]
  if (sheet.getName() == 'A' && range.getColumn() == 25 )
  {
    for(var i=0;i<range.getNumRows();i++)
    {
      var offset=range.getRow() + i;
      var g=sheet.getRange('Y' + offset).getValue();
      var val=sheet.getRange('Z' + offset).getValue();
      if (val== "Not found")
      {
        dat.push(g)  
      }
    }
    
  }

  dat = dat.filter(function(n){ return n != "" });  
  for (var i = 0; i < dat.length; i++) 
  {
    dat[i] = '"' + dat[i] + '"';
  }
  var unique = [...new Set(dat)]
  
  //Initiate Query by calling function runBigQuery
  var values= runBigQuery(unique)
// Append the results to another sheet.
  appendData(sheetName,values)
   
}


Thanks,
```

Comment: please give moe details and code snippets if possible

Comment: I added the script for reference. Hope this gives the idea!

Comment: What makes you think `runBigQuery` is not getting triggered? Have you checked that with some basic logs? Is the code reaching the line `var values= runBigQuery(unique)`? Also, could you provide the code related to `runBigQuery`? Also, are you sure the trigger is installed? Hard to know what's going on with the information provided. Finally, since you are using `getNumRows()`, I assume the edited range contains several rows?

Comment: Thank you for responding. The issue got fixed now. It is because i set trigger from resource. Once i added var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
    ScriptApp.newTrigger("onMyEdit").forSpreadsheet(ss).onEdit()
       .create();, it worked fine!